# Windows Docker image has no internet access

Tags: asp.net, azure, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have an application written in Net 5 Core, but the dependencies must work on the Windows platform and I must use Windows containers. Some values for the application to work are stored in the Azure database. After the build of the image, I launch the container and it crashes due to the inability to read the data from the base. Other applications that can be run under Linux they can read values from the base. Perhaps there are some firewall settings that need to be implemented and Windows images so that they can work?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src


COPY ["/src/Configurations/appsettings.json", "Configurations/"]
COPY ["/src/TestEngine/.", "TestEngine/"]


RUN dotnet restore "TestEngine/TestEngine.App/TestEngine.App.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "TestEngine/TestEngine.App/"
RUN dotnet build "TestEngine.App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build  --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestEngine.App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish  --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestEngine.App.dll"]
```

error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at TestEngine.App.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\src\TestEngine\TestEngine.App\Startup.cs:line 80
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
```

Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be several different things that break internet for windows containers. What solved it for me a few times was a "docker network prune" followed by restarting the computer, so it recreates it's default networks.

A less destructive option was using the "Default Switch" network in your commands, like:

```
docker run --network "Default Switch" ...
docker build --network "Default Switch" ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still can't ping for some reason, but I can to stuff like curl for some strange reason